# Does toc.update also include toc.updatepagenumbers?

Tags: updates, tableofcontents

Does the Table of Contents 'update' command also include the 'updatepagenumbers' command, or do I need both in my code?

```
For Each oTOC In ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents
    oTOC.Update
    oTOC.UpdatePageNumbers 'update TOC's
Next oTOC
```

Answer (score 0):

`Update()` updates both the entries in the TOC and their page numbers, so calling `UpdatePageNumbers()` after is unnecessary.